# how to map data elements to data types

Tags: haskell

I have a data type that looks like this:

```
data MyAwesomeType = MyAwesomeType {
                                     a :: String,
                                     b :: String,
                                     c :: String,
                                     ...
                                     -- 25 in total
                                   } deriving (Show)
```

I have some data that looks like this:

```
let xs = [["A", "B", "C", ...],["D", "E", "F", ...]]
```

with one value for each field in the type.

How can I apply my custom data type to each element in the above list? I was trying to do something like this, which does not work:

```
map (MyAwesomeType) xs
```

Comment: I'll probably be scolded for that, so it's not an answer, but you can use Template Haskell to define such a function based on the fields in your datatype. You can construct it so that it matches only a list with a specific number of strings, and gracefully fails on anything else. You can also write it by hand, obviously, if your type isn't going to change any time soon.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz TH was my first thought as well. But, yes, it is probably overkill, and would require to write more than the obvious function. Scrap-your-boilerplate would probably be simpler and require less typing.

Comment: @chi FWIW I did that as a helper and it's [not that bad](https://github.com/bananu7/Turnip/blob/master/src/Turnip/Eval/TH.hs#L66-L74). Would have to go over fields of the type instead of [my Sig type](https://github.com/bananu7/Turnip/blob/master/src/Turnip/Eval/TH.hs#L16-L18), but otherwise it's pretty much the same deal.

Comment: Unless the OP has a number of such types and (or) will change the type significantly during the development, TH is probably an overkill

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think you should post that, it's nice to see all the possible approaches.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm always amazed at the help and generosity of the Haskell community. I realize this is probably a trivial question, but the discussion is of great help to me.

Comment: @chi I started to write it, but now I'm 6 abstraction levels deep in `Lens` source code. Just made me appreciate your SYB solution more ;) (I'll post it if I can get a stripped-down version to work)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Actually, now I realized that SYB is harder than I thought. My (now deleted) answer actually answered another question. I failed to see that we want to construct `MyAwesomeType` from another type (a list), which is harder. I think SYB might still be used, but it's worse than I thought.

Comment: @turtle: This is not what you asked, but a type holding 25 undifferentiated values is a code smell. If fields "a", "b" and "c" all mean different things (e.g. parameters from a config file) then you should translate the strings into types that mean something to the application, and also try to classify them into a hierarchy of smaller records (e.g. IP config versus application parameters). If you really have a data type holding 25 strings then use an array, vector or list and wrap it in a newtype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a function to convert from the given type to your custom type. In the above example, you need a function

```
myAwesomeTypeConverter :: [String] -> Maybe MyAwesomeType
myAwesomeTypeConverter (a:b:c:[]) = Just $ MyAwesomeType a b c
myAwesomeTypeConverter _ = Nothing
```

Now you can use this function to map over your array

```
map myAwesomeTypeConverter xs
```

Comment: Should be `[String] -> Maybe MyAwesomeType` and have a default match `converter _ = Nothing`. Impartial functions are dangerous!

Comment: I agree. Was just trying to be quick. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe I've transcribed something wrong, but I get `error: Parse error in pattern`.

Comment: @turtle Try now.

Comment: that pattern can be written as `[a,b,c]` as well.

Comment: Partial functions, not impartial, @BartekBanachewicz.

Answer (score 4):

## Three (or small) number of arguments

You can use a *lambda expression* for that:

```
map (\[a,b,c] -> MyAwesomeType a b c) xs
```

Nevertheless it us usually not a good idea to work with such lists anyway: at compile time it is unknown how many elements are in the list, so if there are less, or more than three, this will error. If you want some generic structure to store values in.

You better use a *tuple* (here `(String,String,String)` since now you know that there are three elements, furthermore the elements can have different types (that is not the case with a list):

```
let xs = [("A", "B", "C"),("D", "E", "F")]
--        ^    tuple    ^ ^    tuple    ^
```

Then you can work with:

```
map (\(a,b,c) -> MyAwesomeType a b c) xs
```

## More arguments with template Haskell

In case the number of "arguments" is huge (i.e. 25), then of course this will not be very elegantly. In that case you can decide to work with *template Haskell*, like:

```
module Templates where

import Control.Monad(replicateM)
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax(newName,Pat(ListP,VarP),Exp(LamE,VarE,AppE))

listmap n = do
    xs <- replicateM n $ newName "x"
    f <- newName "f"
    return $ LamE [VarP f,ListP (map VarP xs)] $ foldl AppE (VarE f) $ map VarE xs
```

Now in the your main program, you can use `$(listmap 25)`:

```
*Template> :t $(listmap 25)
$(listmap 25)
  :: (t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t1
      -> t)
     -> [t1] -> t
```

So this constructs a function that takes as input a function that maps 25 `t1`s on a `t` and then constructs a function that maps a list of `t1`s to `t`.

You can then use it like:

```
import Templates(listmap)

{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

map ($(listmap 25) MyAwesomeType) xs
```

As said before however, you better use tuples, you can do this with:

```
module Templates where

import Control.Monad(replicateM)
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax(newName,Pat(TupP,VarP),Exp(LamE,VarE,AppE))

curryN n = do
    xs <- replicateM n $ newName "x"
    f <- newName "f"
    return $ LamE [VarP f,TupP (map VarP xs)] $ foldl AppE (VarE f) $ map VarE xs
```

which can then be used, like:

```
*Templates> :t $(curryN 25)
$(curryN 25)
  :: (t25
      -> t24
      -> t23
      -> t22
      -> t21
      -> t20
      -> t19
      -> t18
      -> t17
      -> t16
      -> t15
      -> t14
      -> t13
      -> t12
      -> t11
      -> t10
      -> t9
      -> t8
      -> t7
      -> t6
      -> t5
      -> t4
      -> t3
      -> t2
      -> t1
      -> t)
     -> (t25, t24, t23, t22, t21, t20, t19, t18, t17, t16, t15, t14,
         t13, t12, t11, t10, t9, t8, t7, t6, t5, t4, t3, t2, t1)
     -> t
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i should have mentioned in my actually application, my type has a huge number of elements. not 3 but 25. is there an easier way than writing them all out like that?

Comment: @turtle: you could define such a function with template Haskell, but I'm not a huge fan of that.

Comment: Wow, your TH solution looks really short and concise. Kudos, what I was attempting required much much more helpers to even wrap my head around the types.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it, using [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language TypeOperators #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP

data MyAwesomeType = MyAwesomeType
                   {
                       a :: String,
                       b :: String,
                       c :: String
                   } deriving (Show,GHC.Generic)

instance Generic MyAwesomeType -- this Generic is from generics-sop

awesomeFromList :: forall c r xs. (Generic r, Code r ~ '[xs], All ((~) c) xs)
                => [c]
                -> Maybe r
awesomeFromList fields =
    to . SOP . Z . hcliftA (Proxy :: Proxy ((~) c)) (mapKI id)
    <$>
    Generics.SOP.fromList fields
```

Works for any uniform record implementing `Generics.SOP.Generic`.

```
*Main> awesomeFromList ["foo","bar","baz"] :: Maybe MyAwesomeType
Just (MyAwesomeType {a = "foo", b = "bar", c = "baz"})
```